# a template declaration cannot appear at block scope (template class in main)

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, inherited-resources

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class List
{
    public:
        List(T);
};
template<typename T>
class A: public List<T>
{
    public:
};
int main()
{   //my problem is here...!
    A a(10);
}
```

I don't know how to declare this class in `main` and use it.
In this case, I have this error:

> missing template arguments before ‘a’

and when I write:

```
template(typename T)
   A a(10);
```

I give this error:

> g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp
>    error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
>        template
>        ^~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u didn't write a constructor for `A`, I supposed u want to use the inherited one, hence u have to provide the following line in `A`

```
using List<T>::List;
```

And since u used `c++11`, u have to provide the template `arg`, as follows

```
A<int> a(10);
```

If u want to make the compiler figure it out, use `c++17` or `c++20` and provide the following guide

```
template<class T> A(T)-> A<T>;
```

Now the full code with `c++17` will be

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List(T) {}
};
template<typename T>
class A: public List<T>
{
public:
    using List<T>::List;
};
template<class T> A(T)-> A<T>;
int main()
{   //No problem here...!
    A a(10);
}
```

And with `c++11` will be

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List(T) {}
};
template<typename T>
class A: public List<T>
{
public:
    using List<T>::List;
};


int main()
{   //No problem here...!
    A<int> a(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector
```

is templated, so you call it as `std::vector<int>` for example. As such, your declaration should be `A<int> a(10);`